# How to use relative paths on windows CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line

OSX I can do this:

```
someCommand -someOtherParameter ../../../../../ThisFileIsNeeded -yetAnotherParameter
```

When I try to do the same thing on Windows it yields:

> "The system cannot find the file specified"

because the result path is something like:

```
c:\myFolder\otherFolder\IamHere\..\..\..\..\ThisFileIsNeeded
```

How can I write relative paths for windows cmd?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Relative paths

Paths, and relative ones, work very similar to what you have in OS X/macOS.

- Windows uses "\", not "/".
- Basically ".." is one level higher
- ".\" is a sub-folder of the current working directory

#### Example

If you are located in `c:\dev\repos\repo1` and you want to do something with a file located in `c:\dev\bin\` (example below for PowerShell).

```
C:\dev\repos\repo1> Start-Process ..\..\bin\my_executable.exe
```

Command line above in words:

Start a process using the file my_executable.exe found (with starting point in the current directory (relative path)) by going two directories back up and then down in to directory **bin**.

**Sub Folder Example** If you are located in `c:\dev\repos\repo1` and you want a sub-folder `\My_Project\repo1.exe` (example below for PowerShell).

```
C:\dev\repos\repo1> Start-Process .\My_Project\repo1.exe
```

---

It seems to me that you do know how relative paths work. Reply with exact commands so that I can reproduce what you're trying.

Comment: `Start-Process` isn’t exactly “cmd style”. :P // With tab autocomplete, working with relative paths is even easier, because you can “look into” the current directory level.

Comment: I am not right now in my Pc but when I use it (although not direct in cmd.exe but in Vscode terminal) all the "\" just get deleted, so `..\bin\my_executable` becomes `c:\myPath\..binmyexecutable.exe`

Comment: @DanielB Haha, true... :)

Comment: @distante That means you’re encountering some bug. It definitely works the way described in this answer. Did you try with a “real” console window yet?

Comment: Weird enough, after a reboot it all works.. even with ./../  (in vs code console an a "real console". I honestly do not know why this happend.